# Are there any open datasets for Wrestling statistics

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm looking for freestyle, greco, and folkstyle statistics. At the "professional" and college level.

To expand on my question (and in response to the comment below), for example, I'm looking for match results from the recent US Open held in Las Vegas. (Real wrestling, not the fake WWE/WWF stuff).

For example, there's a website (trackwrestling.com) that has all of this information, I'd like to know where they get it, and if I could get it as well (since they have not responded to my requests).

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking (http://www.profightdb.com/records.html). If not, can you please improve your question with more info and maybe an example?

Answer (score 6):

FILA keeps an online database of all matches for Amateur/Professional wrestling tournaments worldwide. These are "Olympic" class wrestlers (not WWE). It does not though contain collegiate events. It does have all Olympic related records dating back to 1896

http://www.fila-official.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=768&Itemid=100236&lang=en

The NCAA publishes it's national championship results here:

http://i2.turner.ncaa.com/dr/ncaa/ncaa7/release/sites/default/files/external/gametool/brackets/wrestling_di_2014.pdf

Comment: Great answer. Now if I could also get the collegiate events...

Answer (score 4):

Trackwrestling gets that information from a number of sources.
Primarily, it's the software preferred for the NCAA, so all reporting of dual meets is required to be entered within 24 hours of a dual being completed.

From a tournament standpoint, they run tournament software, so they developed the system and integrated all those tournament scores into their respective databases.

I wouldn't expect them to give anyone other than the NCAA or NWCA that data.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, unless this is a definitive **No** (which I guess it is not from *I wouldn't expect them*)

Answer (score 2):

htttp://www.centermatwrestling.com has up to date college results.